# Filter for android browser's "view image"

Tags: android, image, browser, mime-types, intentfilter

I am writing an application for android 2.2 to download an image from an url and download and display it sequentialy to view input from a webcam.

To input the url for the image/webcam I thought of using android's browser 'View Image' Context menu.
But I have not been able to get it to work.
When I try to view the image with this intent filter, it displays the image in the browser.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:scheme="http" />

</intent-filter>
```

This intent filter works for any http url (links and any other) which is why it is useless in this situation.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Am I missing something? How should I go about it?

Alternatively, where can I get the source code for android's default browser to read up and find out why it behaves that way?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

in my android 4.4 it matches all images uris for file:, content:, http:, htttps: